# Authorized get request not working in UWP

Tags: c#, wpf, http, uwp

Im creating a UWP application that gets data from an ASP.NET API
When im trying to make a request that requires a JWT token it fails.

the request code:

```
public async Task<string> testAsync(string token)
        {
            token = token.Replace("\"", "");

            var authenticationHeaderValue = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = authenticationHeaderValue;

            var json = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:5000/api/TravelList");
            return json.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
```

client is a HttpClient object created like this:

```
client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
            {
                ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (a, b, c, d) => true
            });
```

When I run this code I get:
System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError

And my backend logs this:

`An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.`

But when I test this in on swagger everything works fine:
[swagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YINa5.png)

Note: I am using HTTP instead of HTTPS in my UWP application so I am using http://localhost:5000/... instead of https://localhost:5001/... but also this does work on swagger.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that you are using **System.Net.Http.HttpClient** class instead of **Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient** class. We suggest you use **Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient** class because classes in the **System.Net.Http** are affected by network isolation feature. Please check if you have declared the capability **Private Networks(Client & Server)** and the capability **internet(Client & Server)**. Could you please tell me if you have enabled the [local network loopback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/loopback#enabling-loopback-for-a-uwp-application)?

Comment: I enabled the local network loopback and that did the trick.
I think because I can use HTTPS requests now? 

Also I tried using the Windows.Web.Client.Http.HttpClient like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpclient?view=winrt-19041) but I keep getting:
**the type or namespace name 'Windows'  could not be found**

But I suppose that's because my HttpDataService is in my project.core lib and not in my UWP application. Should I change my service to be in my application? 

Thanks for the fast reply! @YanGu-MSFT

Comment: It seems that you have enabled the network loopback and it worked to solve your problem. Then, you don't need to use the Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient class to replace the original System.Net.Http.HttpClient class, just keep using the original System.Net.Http.HttpClient class.